# A question about Hilbert's Nullstellensatz

Tags: algebraic-geometry

We know that Hilbert's Nullstellensatz is valid for $\Bbb{C}[X]$, as $\Bbb{C}$ is a closed field.

Let us consider the ideal $(x+y,x-y)\subset \Bbb{C}[x,y]$. Clearly, $Z((x+y,x-y))=\{(0,0)\}$. Now note that $x^2+y^3=0$ also satisfies $(0,0)$. Hence, by Hilbert's Nullstellensatz, we should have $(x^2+y^3)^n=f(x,y)(x+y)+g(x,y)(x-y)$ for some $n\in\Bbb{N}$. Is there an explicit way to determine $f(x,y)$ and $g(x,y)$?

Comment: Hint: $x$ and $y$ are in your ideal.

Comment: @AlexYoucis- My question, perhaps, is that is there a generalized algorithm of finding $f(x,y)$ and $g(x,y)$, where the ideal given is not as simple as the one given above?

Comment: There are entire books written about this topic, of which I am not an expert. I would suggest you look at a book like *Varieties, Ideals, and Algorithms*. Good luck!

Comment: I think there is no such way, at least in a general setting. But there is the effective Nullstellensatz, it's not exact, but it's a bound at least.

Comment: I think you can do things like this with [Bucherberger's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buchberger%27s_algorithm). You just have to remember the reduction steps used. It is double-exponential, though, so it is not too practical in general.